Document library web part + column
I have a need and don't know how to solve it. I have a document library and I'm displaying it on a page through a document library web part.
I would like to have on the right side of the listing a column where I can type notes for each document:

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Can you confirm if you are using this Document library web part or any other web part? Are you using "Tiles" view?

What is tile view?

Check this: https://i.sstatic.net/ZLB23.png
